# how to mock a prop that is a callback that updates state?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, babel-jest

this is my code:

```
const [userRegion, setUserRegion] = useState<Region | null>(null);
<MapView
    {...{
      ...(!!myLocation && {
        initialRegion: {
          latitude: myLocation.coords.latitude,
          longitude: myLocation.coords.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0043,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0034,
        },
      }),
      onRegionChangeComplete: (region: Region) => {
        console.log('onRegionChangeComplete region: ', region);
        if (userRegion === null) setUserRegion(region);
      },
    }}>
```

i am having a hard time making test for onRegionChangeComplete prop on MapView, region is a default argument that is calculated when initialRegion is valid, then onRegionChangeComplete is fired, but in jest even when there's initialRegion, its' region is null. i need to make region with proper value like: `{"latitude": -0.000011399388312454881, "latitudeDelta": 0.0004928559064869245, "longitude": 0, "longitudeDelta": 0.00026151537895202637}`
but how?
this is my react-native-maps on my jest.setup:

```
jest.mock('react-native-maps', () => {
  const mockMapTypes = {
    STANDARD: 0,
    SATELLITE: 1,
    HYBRID: 2,
    TERRAIN: 3,
    NONE: 4,
    MUTEDSTANDARD: 5,
  };

  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: MockMapView,
    Marker: MockMapMarkerView,
    MAP_TYPES: mockMapTypes,
    PROVIDER_DEFAULT: 'default',
    PROVIDER_GOOGLE: 'google',
  };
});
```

for the MockMapView this is what i tried to mimic a callback for region and i get value for region but it throws warning:

> Warning: Cannot update a component (`Nearby`) while rendering a
> different component (`MockMapView`). To locate the bad setState() call
> inside `MockMapView`, follow the stack trace as described in
> https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render

```
export class MockMapView extends React.Component<MockMapProps> {
  render() {
    const { testID, onRegionChangeComplete, children, ...props } = this.props;

    return (
      <View
        {...{
          testID,
          onRegionChangeComplete: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(
            onRegionChangeComplete({
              latitude: 11.559064518910894,
              latitudeDelta: 0.006275210816060195,
              longitude: 114.52057879418135,
              longitudeDelta: 0.003400370478630066,
            })
          ),
          ...props,
        }}>
        {children}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried something like this

```
jest.mock('react-native-maps', () => {
  const React = require('react');
  const {View} = require('react-native');
  const {jest} = require('@jest/globals');
  const mockOnRegionChange = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {latitude: 57.7, longitude: 11.93};
  });

  class MockMapView extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const {testID, children, ...props} = this.props;

      return (
        <View
          {...{
            ...props,    // <======= Moved this to the Top
            testID,
            onRegionChangeComplete: mockOnRegionChange,
          }}>
          {children}
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

  
  const mockMapTypes = {
    STANDARD: 0,
    SATELLITE: 1,
    HYBRID: 2,
    TERRAIN: 3,
    NONE: 4,
    MUTEDSTANDARD: 5,
  };

  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: MockMapView,
    MAP_TYPES: mockMapTypes,
    PROVIDER_DEFAULT: 'default',
    PROVIDER_GOOGLE: 'google',
  };
});
```

And I get this as result on debug() with React Testing Library. It says **onRegionChangeComplete={[Function mockConstructor]}**

[image]